# how to install openbravo on windows 7 using postgresql

Tags: windows, postgresql, tomcat6, openbravo

I have been trying to install Openbravo on windows 7 with apache, apache tomcat and postgresql. Everything seems to be fine. and the build was also successful. when I try to open the page http://{mylocalhost:8080}/openbravo it does not work. I have already followed the openbravo custom installation steps.

I am new to apache and tomcat. Please provide me with the detailed steps if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: before checking openbravo. Is apache tomcat wokring properly? `http://localhost:8080` ?

Comment: can you add more description to your post... steps you followed to install openbravo Use this documentation http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Development_Stack_Setup and also make sure that you use tomcat 6 for openbravo not tomcat7

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the environment variable for Tomcat correctly. You need to define it as CATALINA_HOME. Also check if the after compilation the codebase is deployed in the webapps directory of tomact.

Answer (score -1):

you must verify the context in CATALINA_HOME, follow this instruction [Installing Apache Tomcat on Microsoft Windows](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50:Openbravo_environment_installation)